# Back button Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I added a back button to a window in my Titanium app, but I am having problems with the behaviour of the button.

It is working fine as it's closing the window when I click it, however when I want to open again the window that was closed, is not opening it.

That is the code in the external.js file (where I am creating the Window):

```
var myModule = require('app.js');
var win = myGlobalVar;

var backButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        title:'Back',
        width : 40,
        height : 40,
        top : 40,
        left : 5
});

win.add(backButton);


backButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("You clicked the button");

    win.close();
});
```

And this is the part of the code in app.js, where I click to open the window (News_tab is a tab where I open the window):

```
            var w= Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                 barColor:"#000000",
                 title:titleText,
                 backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"
                });


            myGlobalVar = w;
            w = require ('external.js');
            News_tab.window = w;

            News_tab.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove or alter the root window of a tab. And if you want to open a window inside a tab, you don't need to assign a new window to the tab, but instead you do

```
News_tab.open(w);
```

This will open the `w` window inside your `News_tab` tab. Assuming `News_tab` is a `Ti.UI.Tab`.

If you then close the `w` window, it will pop back to the root window automatically. This is all assuming it is a Ti.UI.Tab.

If it is a Window you just need to do `w.open()`. If it is a navigationWindow then it is iOS only, and in that case you need to use `openWindow` unless you use `xp.ui` library.

Comment: I am getting an error message: "-[__NSDictionaryM processForSafeArea]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c023a5c0"  If I use News_tab.open(w); Instead of News_tab.window = w; News_tab.open();

Comment: What is `News_tab`

Comment: Edited my answer. If you get that error, it most likely is not a Ti.UI.Tab.

Comment: Yes it is a tab. See the code I use to create it.       var News_tab = Ti.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'images/feed_white.png',
    title:'News',
    window:windowNews
});               Then I add the News_tab to the tabGroup

Comment: i think the key could be in this line  w = require ('external.js'), as I need to open the window in a new file, and I had to change the way I assign the js file to the Window.(The url in the window is deprecated)